# Finding of how many of search keywords are present in the MySQL result reocord

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm having a problem with my ranking algorithm.

I'm running this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT    *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE "%string_1%" OR field_name LIKE "%string_2%" OR field_name LIKE "%string_3%" OR field_name LIKE "%string_4%"
```

There might be more than 1 occurrence of each string and there even might be more than 1 string present in a record.

How can I find that how many and which one of these strings are present in the result record?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

```
SELECT field_name, COUNT(field_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE "%string_1%" 
OR field_name LIKE "%string_2%" 
OR field_name LIKE "%string_3%" 
OR field_name LIKE "%string_4%"
GROUP BY field_name
```

You can return all fields by using `table_name.*` instead of `field_name`